# exec cp command fault "find: missing argument to '-exec'

Tags: linux, exec, root, var, cp

questions is list all files and folders without root user and starting with "n" at var directory.

At below I am trying to copy result to home directory

my bash command is: `find /var ! -user root -name "n*" -exec cp {} /home`

What is wrong!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-r` to `cp` and `\;` at the end of the command: [why \;](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)

The command is : `find /var ! -user root -name "n*" -exec cp -r {} /home \;`